# JSON in YAML settings Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, yaml, gcloud

I'm deploying an app through gcloud on App Engine.
There is an env.yaml file that I need to modify, then I upload it in a bucket, the file contains the settings and secrets:

```
env_variables:
  DB_URL: XXX
  URL: YYY
  JSON_SETTINGS: '{"api": {"secret":"mySecret"}}'
```

There are hundred of settings in JSON_SETTINGS, and for the deployment to work I have to send it on one line. But it's not handy.

When I use a formatter to expand the JSON, I got an error :
`googlecloudsdk.api_lib.app.yaml_parsing.YamlParseError: An error occurred while parsing file`

Do you have any idea how to handle it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Your YAML should be good. By quoting the `JSON_SETTINGS`, the JSON is treated as the value. Why must it be a single line? Why are you using a JSON formatter on YAML?

Comment: Couple of things. You can use a block delimiter in YAML. A paragraph (`|`). As in `JSON_SETTINGS: |` and then the JSON content indented (!) and starting on the line be below. You can then layout over multiple lines.

Comment: You can also use `"\"x\": \"something\""` to escape too.

Comment: Hi OP, could you add more details to the point where we can reproduce this error? Also, may I know if the suggestions offered by DazWilkin worked out for you?

Comment: @DazWilkin, the solution with: JSON_SETTINGS: >- and the json settings on multiple lines seem to work. I'm not sure yet, because I'm facing other issues, but the JSON inside the YAML is correct now. Thanks

Comment: @DazWilkin your comment is helpful for the OP. Will you post it as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Your YAML should be good.

By quoting the `JSON_SETTINGS`, the JSON is treated as the value. Why must it be a single line? Why are you using a JSON formatter on YAML?

Couple of things:

You can use a block delimiter in YAML. A paragraph (`|`). As in `JSON_SETTINGS: |` and then the JSON content indented (!) and starting on the line be below. You can then layout over multiple lines.

You can also use `"\"x\": \"something\""` to escape too.